# Vulkan resolve attachment is flipped

Tags: vulkan, msaa

[image]

I use pResolveAttachment to implement MSAA with Vulkan on Android, but the result is flipped.

```
    VkSubpassDescription subpassDesc;
    subpassDesc.flags = 0;
    subpassDesc.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpassDesc.inputAttachmentCount = 0;
    subpassDesc.pInputAttachments = nullptr;
    subpassDesc.colorAttachmentCount = colorAttachmentCount;
    subpassDesc.pColorAttachments = attachmentRefs.data();
    subpassDesc.pResolveAttachments = resolveAttachmentCount > 0 ? resolveReferences.data() : nullptr;
    subpassDesc.pDepthStencilAttachment = depthStencilAttachment;
    subpassDesc.preserveAttachmentCount = 0;
    subpassDesc.pPreserveAttachments = nullptr;
```

```
// TIPS
resolveReferences[resolveAttachmentCount].attachment = attachmentCount;
resolveReferences[resolveAttachmentCount].layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

resolveAttachmentCount++;

....

subpassDesc.pResolveAttachments = resolveAttachmentCount > 0 ? resolveReferences.data() : nullptr;
```

Comment: I wander whether the result is correspond to the NDC coordinate system and texture  coordinate system.

Comment: That's curious - what device are you using?

Comment: android, and the cpu is  snapdragon 835

Comment: Weird, I've got some MSAA test code and I've just tested it on a device with the same chipset and it's not flipping for me. I can't think of anything in the resolve path that would have that effect

Comment: yes, it's very weird, maybe I set some wrong parameters for the pipeline object.

Comment: If you are using the oculus mobile SDK, I unfortunately don't have a solution, but I might have an explanation:
Oculus documentation state that vrapi_EnterVrMode() is called from an OpenGL ES context, current on the Android window surface. I guess that explains this behavior.